# Using a function call with lazy attribute results in a compile error

Tags: swift

When I call the following, the compiler complains that I am missing argument for parameter #1 in call :

```
import Foundation

class Person {

    func uniqueID() -> String {
        return NSUUID().UUIDString
    }

    lazy var sessionID: String = uniqueID()

}


let p = Person()

p.sessionID
p.sessionID
p.sessionID
```

When I replace the line with:

```
lazy var sessionID: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

It works.

What is causing the problem calling the function in a lazy initialization?

Interestingly, calling a closure works, even if the syntax looks clunky and heavy, as I would have to guard it if self is a weak reference:

```
lazy var sessionID: String = {
    return self.uniqueID()
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're missing the reference to self. You have it in the closure but not in the direct method call.

```
lazy var sessionID = self.uniqueID()
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I always use self. when I call methods idiomatically? Omitting it on traditional calls seems to work, but 'lazy' behaves differently. Why is that?

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks like a lazy initialization is essentially always treated as a closure, so they follow the rule that self must be explicit.